# Generate a row with values = values of previous row + variation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a pandas dataframe in which the value of each cell is the value of the cell above it + a variation.

I've found a way to do almost what I want...

```
import pandas as pd, random

max_deviation = 20
nb_periods = 5
colnames = ["col1", "col2"]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = colnames)
df.loc[0] = 500
for id_period in range(1, nb_periods):
    df.loc[id_period] = df.loc[id_period-1] + random.randint(-max_deviation, max_deviation)

df

    col1 col2
0    500  500
1    485  485
2    479  479
3    479  479
4    496  496
```

Except that of course, the `random.randint(-max_deviation_each_period, max_deviation_each_period)` which is applied at each row is the same for each cell. What I want would be something like that :

```
    col1 col2
0    500  500
1    485  503
2    479  522
3    479  511
4    496  494
```

How could I achieve this ?

Comment: Do you want the variation to be applied to both columns separately without any relation to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you what you're looking for. Generate N * M random numbers, find their cumulative sum along the 0<sup>th</sup> axis, add the offset (which is `500`), and load into a dataframe.

```
i = 5           # number of rows
j = 2           # number of columns
max_dev = 20    # maximum deviation
```

```
v = np.random.randint(-max_dev, max_dev + 1, (i, j)).cumsum(axis=0) + 500
df = pd.DataFrame(v).rename(columns=lambda x: x + 1).add_prefix('col')

df

   col1  col2
0   490   484
1   473   473
2   477   457
3   484   465
4   465   480
```

If you want the result to begin with `500`, then call `shift` + `fillna` on the result above -

```
df.shift().fillna(500).astype(int)

   col1  col2
0   500   500
1   490   484
2   473   473
3   477   457
4   484   465
```

---

If you like, turn this into a function -

```
def foo(i, j, max_dev=20, offset=500):
    v = np.random.randint(-max_dev, max_dev + 1, (i, j)).cumsum(axis=0) + offset

    return pd.DataFrame(v)\
             .rename(columns=lambda x: x + 1)\
             .add_prefix('col')\
             .shift()\
             .fillna(offset)\
             .astype(int)
```

Now, call it with the appropriate parameters -

```
foo(5, 5)

   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0   500   500   500   500   500
1   491   497   489   512   501
2   480   502   501   495   486
3   499   490   481   477   500
4   503   494   488   496   512
```

Comment: What do you think about my answer?

Comment: @jezrael Hmm, yours is similar to mine and Willem Van Onsem's except for the minor details... is that deliberate?

Comment: @coldspeed - hmm, sure. But I think it is different between your `shift` and `v[0]`, or not?

Comment: @jezrael, The main part of the answer is generating the numbers with `np.random.randint(-20, 20, (i, j)).cumsum(axis=0) + 500`. The other things are minor details, in my opinion. But its upto you.

Comment: There's actually a mistake in your answer : `np.random.randint(-20, 20, (i, j))` can output a value of `-20`, but will never output a cell with a value of `20`.

Comment: @fmalaussena So, it should be 21? `max_dev + 1`?

Answer (score 2):

What you describe here is basically a *Brownian motion*. We can do this by first generating a random array:

We can first generate a number of random numbers:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ['col1', 'col2']
initial = 500

max_deviation = 20
nb_periods = 5

delta = np.random.randint(low=-max_deviation,
                          high=max_deviation+1,
                          size=(nb_periods, len(columns)))
delta[0] = initial
```

Then we load the *cumulative sum* of `delta` into the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(delta.cumsum(axis=0), columns=columns)
```

This then produces:

```
>>> df
   col1  col2
0   500   500
1   499   497
2   485   513
3   487   508
4   503   489
```

Answer (score 1):

Small modification to your code works (creating values separately for 2 columns):

```
max_deviation = 20
nb_periods = 5
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["col1", "col2"])
df.loc[0] = 500
for id_period in range(1, nb_periods):
    # separate for 2 columns:
    df.loc[id_period,"col1"] = df.loc[id_period-1,"col1"] + random.randint(-max_deviation, max_deviation)
    df.loc[id_period,"col2"] = df.loc[id_period-1,"col2"] + random.randint(-max_deviation, max_deviation)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    col1   col2
0  500.0  500.0
1  502.0  519.0
2  513.0  510.0
3  520.0  513.0
4  512.0  509.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create numpy array first with [`numpy.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html), set first row to `0` and call `cumsum`. Last use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
max_deviation = 20
nb_periods = 5
offset = 500
cols = 2

v = np.random.randint(-max_deviation, max_deviation, (nb_periods, cols)).cumsum(axis=0)
v[0] = 0
v += offset

df = pd.DataFrame(v).rename(columns = lambda x: 'col{}'.format(x+1))
print (df)
   col1  col2
0   500   500
1   505   514
2   517   499
3   518   491
4   512   472
```

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, I came up with an answer too. Probably not the best, but it works and it's a different approach (basically, I'm filling every cell with it's value).

```
colnames = ["col1", "col2"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = colnames)
max_deviation = 20
nb_periods = 5
df.loc[0] = 500
for id_period in range(1, nb_periods):
    df.loc[id_period] = None
    for column in colnames:
        df[column][id_period] = df[column][id_period-1] + random.randint(-max_deviation, max_deviation)

df
```